# Use OpenGL on the nvidia card instead of the Intel integrated one

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, opengl

I have a visualization workstation to which I connect via SSH (iGLX should be enabled since I can run `glxgears` over SSH) that is shipped with a Titan X card and also a Matrox adapter that I believe is the adapter to the integrated Intel Iris VGA. I installed latest CUDA using the repository packages (and not w/ the runfile). I successfully compiled and run (few of) the CUDA sample programs that are executing correctly.

The problem I'm experiencing is that it seems to me that the GL applications are not run using OpenGL over nVidia card but instead over the Integrated one (or even maybe using MESA CPU emulated OpenGL).

```
glxinfo| grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I also checked the `libGL.so` and it seems to be installed somehow by MESA and not by nVidia:

```
locate libGL
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.410.79
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.410.79
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.410.79
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/cuda-10.0/samples/common/lib/linux/aarch64/libGLEW.a
/usr/local/cuda-10.0/samples/common/lib/linux/armv7l/libGLEW.a
/usr/local/cuda-10.0/samples/common/lib/linux/x86_64/libGLEW.a
```

Shouldn't the CUDA packages also install GL libraries (and replace `libGL.so`?)

### Hardware Specs

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-410:amd64                   410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-410                       410.79-0ubuntu1                              all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-410:amd64                410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-410:amd64                 410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-410:amd64                 410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-410:amd64                   410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-410:amd64                     410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-410:amd64                   410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-410                   410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-410                            410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-410                          410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-410                   410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-410                   410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-modprobe                            410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.8.2                                      all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-410                           410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410              410.79-0ubuntu1                              amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4114 CPU @ 2.20GHz

```
lspci | grep -i vga
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics Controller (rev 04)
3b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [TITAN Xp] (rev a1)
```

```
nvidia-smi 
Mon Jan 21 11:03:27 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.79       Driver Version: 410.79       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN Xp            On   | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   30C    P8    10W / 250W |      0MiB / 12196MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi @DiTTiD, thanks for posting your question here, I actually have the same problem, could you derive a solution btw?

Comment: Ehi @MJimitater, I got a partially working solution creating a new X server instance bound to the Nvidia card. I still have Paraview crashing (that is the app I needed), but I think I was pretty close, unfortunately I exhausted my time to dedicate on this endeavour :). [Here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/glxinfo-still-shows-llvmpipe-or-incomplete-nvidia-while-cuda-is-working-perfectly/107283/6) the link on Nvidia forums where they helped me getting close to solve the problem. If you end up succeeding, don't forget to post an answer.

Comment: Dear @DiTTiD, thanks for your reply, I also encountered the problem of not getting OpenGL app to run on Nvidia card but on Intel instead, but only yesterday I managed to solve it using Nvidias new kind of feature [off-loading](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/435.17/README/primerenderoffload.html). This let me not worry too much about the X server, as the workload is automatically shared. Not sure if this applies to your issue and whether your setup allows *off-loading*, but I thought I'd pass it on to you, perhaps its of any use for you. Cheers

Comment: Running `NVidia X  Server Settings` then select NVidia in PRIME Profiles sections should fix it.